# How to disable request validation in ASP.NET MVC, IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-express

.Net Framework 4.5.2, Visual Studio 2015, IIS Express

I want to send requests like `http://localhost:49974/xxx/xml/<a><b></b></a>` to my application. This results in a server error and the message: `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (="/xxx/xml/<a><b></b></a>").`

Following the instructions from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx) I have set `requestValidationMode="2.0"`:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
```

And and added `[ValidateInput(false)]` to cotrtoller's action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Xml()
{
    return View("../Home/Index");
}
```

However I still get exactly the same error on the request presented above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to convert the acionmethod to use a model for receiving the data, you can specify the `[AllowHtml]` Attribute on the modelproperty.

This also ensures that the validation is only skipped for this specific property.

ActionMethod:

```
public ActionResult Xml(XmlModel vm)
{
    return View("../Home/Index");
}
```

Model

```
public class XmlModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string xml { get; set; }
}
```

your url would look like http://localhost:49974/xxx/xml/?xml={your xml string}

Comment: ok I see, but is there any way to configure the validation of the URI? I know sending a XML in URI is a bad idea but it's the simplest thing I could think of and I would like to make it work.

Comment: In my experience i've found that allowing this using a model works best and is a safer way than disabling requestvalidation on your entire method / application. It is still possible to send the xmldata through the url. See my editted answer for an example